# MongoDB: Convert Date String (mm/dd/yyyy) to Unix timestamp

Tags: mongodb, unix-timestamp, milliseconds, robo3t

just practicing my MongoDB queries and I've hit a wall with a field data type.

I'm currently using Robomongo as GUI for accessing the production database.

My document structure looks like:

[image: Robomongo Document Structure]

Is there a MongoDB operator or way/method to convert the `date` field value, currently in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, to a Unix timestamp so we can perform filter operations?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all your items and update one by one with the conversion to `Date`. Here is an example to convert your date from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `ISODate` :

```
db.test.find().forEach( function(res){

      if (typeof(res.date)=="string"){
        var arr = res.date.split("/");
        res.date = new Date(arr[2], arr[0] - 1, arr[1]);
        db.test.save(res)
      }
    }
)
```

For Unix timestamp (millis from epoch), you can call `getTime()` from `Date` :

```
db.test.find().forEach( function(res){

      if (typeof(res.date)=="string"){
        var arr = res.date.split("/");
        res.date = new Date(arr[2], arr[0] - 1, arr[1]).getTime();
        db.test.save(res)
      }
    }
)
```

Note that these dates will be converted into UTC format, so you may want to change temporarily your timezone before doing your conversion

You can also use [bulk update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/) if you want to optimize update performance

You can also just convert your date to `yyyy-mm-dd` which will preserve sorting (check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021363/mongodb-sorting-date-string-mm-dd-yyyy)). The following will decompose your date field into `day`,`month` and `year`, set date field with the new format and write output in a new collection named `test2` :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        startTime: 1,
        endTime: 1,
        date: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    year: { $substr: ["$date", 6, 10] },
                    month: { $substr: ["$date", 0, 2] },
                    dayOfMonth: { $substr: ["$date", 3, 2] }
                },
                in : { $concat: ["$$year", "-", "$$month", "-", "$$dayOfMonth"] }
            }
        }
    }
},{
    $out :"test2"
}])
```

Comment: Thanks @BertrandMartel.  This is really helpful however I was looking to keep this within MongoDB as this is part of an aggregate query.  If it all possible I'm looking to avoid using Javascript, PHP, etc. to make the conversion.  Is there a process using various MongoDB operators to achieve this?

Comment: I've updated my post with a way to convert your string date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` which is not what you want in the first place but will preserve sorting compare to `mm-dd-yyyy`